# Evaluating the integral $\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos^{3/2}x}{\sin x\sqrt{\lambda-2\cos x-2\ln(1-\cos x)+2\ln(\sin x)}}\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, closed-form, trigonometric-integrals

I'm trying to find this indefinite integral

$$\int\frac{\cos^{3/2} x}{\sin x\sqrt{(\lambda-2\cos x-2\ln(1-\cos x)+2\ln(\sin x))}} \,\mathrm dx$$

Or 
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos^{3/2}x}{\sin x\sqrt{\lambda-2\cos x-2\ln(1-\cos x)+2\ln(\sin x)}}\,\mathrm dx$$

Where $\lambda>2$

Which sub I take !?

I don't have any ideas for this type  integration

Please give me ideas [image]

Comment: You should edit your question so we can properly see the integral.. I'm not exactly sure what you typed in or I'd edit it myself

Comment: Yes sir correct , thank you very much

Comment: Where did you find this integral? do you know if it has a closed form value?